# Adding single column ones to a matrix in NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a this function that adds column vector of ones to a matrix.

```
def add_ones(x):
    return np.hstack((np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)), x))
```

when x is a matrix it does it's job fine. For example:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.zeros((5, 5))
add_ones(x)
add_ones(y)
```

gives

```
[[1. 1. 2.]
 [1. 3. 4.]]
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

however when I pass it a single vector:

```
z = np.zeros(5)
add_ones(z)
```

it gives this error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I'd like it to return

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function creates a 2d array of ones, right?

```
def add_ones(x):
    return np.hstack((np.ones((x.shape[0], 1)), x))
```

That is fine with `x` is also 2d.  But when `x` is 1d, that is wrong.  Your function needs to pay attention the shape of `x` and create a 1d array when appropriate.

Something like:

```
def add_ones(x):
    if x.ndim == 1:
        y = np.ones(1, x.dtype)
    elif x.ndim ==2:
        y = np.ones((x.shape[0],1), x.dtype)
    else: < do something else>
    return np.hstack((y, x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It's kinda annoying that whenever I extract column vector from a matrix NumPy just automatically turns it into a row vector.

Comment: No it creates a 1d array.  That's not the same as a column or row vector.  Those are MATLAB terms, where everything is 2d.  `x[:, [1]]` produces a (n,1) array.

Comment: Indexing with a slice also preserves a dimension, `x[:, 1:2]`.  `x[:,1, None]` also works.  `None` or `np.newaxis` is a good idiomatic way of adding a singleton dimension where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You must add another dimension to `z` (make it a two-dimensional 5x1 matrix):

```
add_ones(z[:, np.newaxis])
#array([[ 1.,  0.],
 #      [ 1.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  0.],
#       [ 1.,  0.]])
```